# exiftool: delete exif data but preserve some specific tags

Tags: macos, command-line, unix, exif, exiftool

Currently I use exiftool with the **-all=** option and it deletes all the EXIF data from my photos:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= /Users/andyl/photos/*.jpg
```

Now I want exiftool to delete all the EXIF information but NOT the photo's title, caption and keywords.

How I can achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should always check the man pages if you are in trouble.

```
man exiftools
```

Which should read something like this:

```
--TAG

    Exclude specified tag from extracted information.  Same as the -x
    option.  May also be used following a -tagsFromFile option to
      exclude tags from being copied, or to exclude groups from being
    deleted when deleting all information (ie. "-all= --exif:all"
    deletes all but EXIF information).  But note that this will not
    exclude individual tags from a group delete.  Instead, individual
    tags may be recovered using the -tagsFromFile option (ie. "-all=
    -tagsfromfile @ -artist").  Wildcards are permitted as described
    above for -TAG.
```

Something like:

```
exiftool -overwrite_original -all= -tagsFromFile @ -title -caption -keywords /Users/andyl/photos/*.jpg
```

should work. Ensure that the tags really are named this way using `exif /path/to/file.jpg`.

What the command does? `-all=` deletes all the tags, `-tagsFromFile @` takes the listed flags from the source file, in this case `@` represents the current file, (you could of course substitute with a fixed file here like `-tagsFromFile pic.jpg`) and writes them to the destination.

Comment: PS my caption gets deleted too (with the -caption parameter), is there any way to keep it?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to delete certain tags from the original file (i.e. no transfer from tags between files, but from within the same file), you do not need the `-tagsFromFile` switch, but a `<` to tell to transfer them along the file.

<sub>**Note:** As of now (version 10.79) `-common<common` cannot set [composite tags](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Composite.html) and therefore using `-common` to transfer tags will break things, e.g. tranferring `Flash` to `Model`. Therefore, my code is explicit and includes every tag that `-common` would normally include. Seems to be a good idea, anyway.</sub>

```cs
exiftool -All:All= \
         -DateTimeOriginal<DateTimeOriginal \
         -Model<Model \
         -LensModel<LensModel \
         -FocalLength<FocalLength \
         -ISO<ISO \
         -ExposureTime<ExposureTime -ShutterSpeedValue<ShutterSpeedValue -BulbDuration<BulbDuration \
         -ApertureValue<ApertureValue -FNumber<FNumber \
         -WhiteBalance<WhiteBalance \
         -Flash<Flash \
         test.jpg
  # Or, if you want to use `-TagsFromFile`:
exiftool -All:All= \
         -TagsFromFile test.jpg \
         -DateTimeOriginal \
         -Model \
         -LensModel \
         -FocalLength \
         -ISO \
         -ExposureTime -ShutterSpeedValue -BulbDuration \
         -ApertureValue -FNumber \
         -WhiteBalance \
         -Flash \
         test.jpg
```

**Please also note** that my code contradicts the [exiftool application documentation](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/exiftool_pod.html#COPYING-EXAMPLES), which includes samples that I simply could not get to work with this task at hand (and version 10.79).

Answer (score -3):

To delete all data using exif tool:

Rename `exiftool(-k).exe` to

```
exiftool (-overwrite_original -all= -k).exe
```

This solves many problems