# remove all exif tags except specified

Tags: exif, exiftool

I just want to remove all tags except a few (from jpg files). I would like to keep only the title,description and the tags.
When i'm running the following command:

> **exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -Title -Caption -Keywords**

my description gets deleted.
Can anyone help me out?

BTW if I enter the description manually, it is not readable by many sites

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exiftool: delete exif data but preserve some specific tags](https://superuser.com/questions/450838/exiftool-delete-exif-data-but-preserve-some-specific-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your description gets deleted because you aren't copying the description.  Follow [Exiftool FAQ #2](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/faq.html#Q2) to make sure, but your description is probably in `Description`, maybe in `Caption-Abstract` or `ImageDescription`.  Note that there is no Caption tag, it's `Caption-Abstract`.

Also take note that you're mixing XMP tags (Title) and Legacy IPTC tags (Keywords).  The XMP tag for Keywords is `Subject`.  You want to double check where your data actually is with `exiftool -g1 -s -a`

To cover all possibilities, you might try this command.  I've put both XMP and the Legacy IPTC versions in the command to be copied.
`exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -Title -ObjectName -Description -Caption-Abstract -Subject -Keywords`

Comment: I used exiftool -a -g1 -s to get all tags and added the following tags -Caption-Abstract -Description -ImageDescription