# ExifTool: Remove all meta data except specific tags

Tags: exiftool

I am trying to remove all meta data from JPEG files except common photo tags as listed with `exiftool -common` (camera model, shutter speed, aperture, ISO, etc.) lens model, color space and embedded ICC profile.

Using the answer from question [exiftool: delete exif data but preserve some specific tags](https://superuser.com/questions/450838/exiftool-delete-exif-data-but-preserve-some-specific-tags), the following commands are produced. The problem is that both of them result in removing shutter speed, aperture and the embedded ICC profile as can be verified using `exiftool` with the respective flags.

```
exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -common -LensModel -ColorSpace -icc_profile:all original.JPG

exiftool -all= -tagsFromFile @ -common -aperture -ShutterSpeed -LensModel -ColorSpace -icc_profile:all original.JPG
```

They both produce warning:

```
Warning: Sorry, filesize is not writable
```

Are the commands malformed or is this an ExifTool bug? This behaviour is confirmed on ExifTool version 10.40.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exiftool: delete exif data but preserve some specific tags](https://superuser.com/questions/450838/exiftool-delete-exif-data-but-preserve-some-specific-tags)

Comment: Using the answer from the referenced question, one gets the unexpected result pointed out in my question.

Comment: I shifted [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1295929/703240) to that question - I tested mine and it works.

Comment: Also note that v`10.40` is from january 2017 - v`10.79` was released recently. The latest production release is v`10.55` - in June 2017.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. Please also note that the flags containing the < sign will not work on Linux upon encapsulation with apostrophes.

Comment: Glad I could help :-) You mean that you have to escape `<`? May I ask how you do that? Then I can add it into my answer (you could edit it as well).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have meant. Writing `'<'` suffices but one can wrap the whole parameter, e.g. `'common<common'`. However, I cannot seem to make the command work as expected. The resulting images lack information about shutter speed and aperture and even Camera Model Name reads "Off, Did not fire". Adding `'-aperture<aperture' -ShutterSpeed<ShutterSpeed'` after `'-common<common' has no effect.

Comment: would you mind switching over to my answer? I now edited it so `-common` is not needed any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Common` shortcut tag is more of a data collection tag and it really isn't meant for copying info from one file to another (see [Shortcut tags](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Shortcuts.html) for list of tags is contains).  Many of that tags covered by that shortcut are either filesystem tags (`FileSize`), MakerNotes tags (`Quality`), or Composite tags (`Aperture`, `ShutterSpeed`).  In the case of `FileSize`, you obviously can't arbitrarily change the size of the destination file, thus the `filesize is not writable` error.

In the case of Makernotes tags, they cannot be copied or created individually.  It has to be copied as a block with `-MakerNotes`.  You may not have been trying to copy the `Quality` tag, but this point becomes relevant when it comes to Composite tags.

[Composite tags](https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/Composite.html) aren't tags that are in the file.  They are derived from multiple other tags.  `Aperture` and `ShutterSpeed` are two examples.  You can't copy them to another file because individually, they don't exist.  You have to copy the tags that they're based upon.  `Aperture` is based upon either `FNumber` or `ApertureValue`, depending upon which is actually in the file.  `ShutterSpeed` is based upon `ExposureTime`,  `ShutterSpeedValue`, and/or `BulbDuration`.  To correctly "copy" `Aperture` and `ShutterSpeed`, you have to copy the above tags that they're based upon.  And some of those tags may be only in the MakerNotes, so you would have to copy the entire Makernotes

`ICC_Profile` is considered an "unsafe" tag and will not be copied unless it is explicitly listed.  You probably have to copy it as a block with `-ICC_Profile` if `-ICC_Profile:all` doesn't work as some of the individual tags in the `ICC_Profile` are not writable.

tl;dr:  There's nothing wrong with the exiftool command, it just doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: liked the `tl;dr:` and Totally agree with it.